# Error al buscar el archivo - FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quería hacer una sencilla aplicación que me lea un fichero `.txt` pero no consigo definir correctamente la ruta.

Mis dos ficheros, `.py` y `.txt` están en la misma carpeta pero al ejecutar el código, la terminal muestra el siguiente mensaje de error.

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './token.txt'

El código es muy sencillo, básicamente defino la ruta y lo imprimo.

```
text_file = open('./token.txt','r')
print(text_file.read())
```

Como veis he probado a añadir en la ruta `./` para que entienda que el `.txt` está en la misma carpeta, también he probado `.\` y quitándolo y tampoco va.

Alguien

Comment: Si están en la misma carpeta y no estás creando un ejecutable con PyInstaller o similares, el código es correcto. La causa más obvia del error es que no sea ese el nombre verdadero del fichero típicamente `'./token.txt.txt'` en Windows con las extensiones ocultas... o `'./.token.txt'` en *nix con archivos ocultos... muéstranos que imprime `import os;
print(os.listdir())`. La otra causas más obvia es que el directorio de trabajo se cambiara antes de éste punto y ya no sea el mismo que el del script principal.

Comment: Con `import os; print(os.listdir())` he encontrado el problema! Se había duplicado la extensión. Muchas gracias!!!